Database from a different Sheet
I'm trying to get all the data from cell range C6:K105 from Sheet1 and save it to Sheet14 but I'm only getting results from cell range C6:C14. Can anyone help me with this VBA code? Thanks
This is the macro VBA code I'm trying to create.
Sub Save()

    Set Database = Sheet14.Range("A1:I1")
    Set New_Input = Sheet1.Range("C6:K105")

    Last_Row = Database.Rows.Count + 1
    
    While Database.Cells(Last_Row, 1) <> ""
        Last_Row = Last_Row + 1:
    Wend
    
    For i = 1 To New_Input.Rows.Count
        If New_Input.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            New_Data = New_Input.Cells(i, 1)
            Database.Cells(Last_Row, i) = New_Data
        End If
    Next i

End Sub


Copy Matching Rows
Option Explicit

Sub CopyNonBlankRows()
    
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 1
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim Data() As Variant, sr As Long, dr As Long, cCount As Long, c As Long
    
    With Sheet1.Range("C6:K105")
        ' Write range values to array.
        Data = .Value
        ' Move matching (not blank) rows to the top of the array.
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        For sr = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If Len(CStr(Data(sr, CRITERIA_COLUMN))) > 0 Then ' is not blank
                dr = dr + 1
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
                Next c
            End If
        Next sr
        ' Check if no matching rows.
        If dr = 0 Then
            MsgBox "All cells are blank in range """ _
                & .Columns(CRITERIA_COLUMN).Address(0, 0) & """ of sheet """ _
                & .Worksheet.Name & """!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim drrg As Range, dlcell As Range
    
    ' Reference the first 'available' row.
    With Sheet14.Range("A1").Resize(, cCount)
        Set drrg = .Rows(1)
        Set dlcell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If Not dlcell Is Nothing Then
            Set drrg = drrg.Offset(dlcell.Row - .Row + 1)
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Copy values from the top of the array to the destination range.
    drrg.Resize(dr).Value = Data
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub



Last_Row = Last_Row + 1 should be included in For loop.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.End property (Excel)


Range.Resize property (Excel)


Range.End property (Excel)

Sub Save()
    Dim Database As Worksheet, New_Input As Worksheet
    Dim Last_Row As Long, i As Long
    Const START_COL_IN = "C"
    Const START_COL_DB = "A"
    Set Database = Sheet14
    Set New_Input = Sheet1
    With Database
        Last_Row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, START_COL_DB).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
    With New_Input
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, START_COL_IN).End(xlUp).Row
            If Len(.Cells(i, START_COL_IN)) > 0 Then
                Database.Cells(Last_Row, START_COL_DB).Reszie(1,9).Value = .Cells(i, START_COL_IN).Reszie(1,9).Value
                Last_Row = Last_Row + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

